# SCCM Distributed software install hangs

Tags: software-distribution, configurationmanager, sccm

I am having issues getting distributed software from SCCM to install properly. This goes for both MSIs and EXEs. The software deploys properly and the respected installer, msiexec or setup.exe, start, and can be viewed in task manager, but the software never installs. The process actually stays open in task manager and never finishes. There are no errors in execmgr.log.

I have tried running from the distribution point, downloading and running locally, running with admin rights, and running as local user. I am at a loss.

I know one particular install requires you to click next once even though it has the command line switches to run a silent install. All distributed software from SCCM installs hidden from the client (even if the program is told to run Maximized), so Next can not be clicked. Is there a way around that?

The programs that are not installing all run fine when I put the same command into cmd.exe that I put in the Command line in SCCM.

Any ideas to try?

Comment: Update for people that may run across this. The MSI was hanging because a condition set in the MSI that would not install because a reboot was pending (even though that was not the case). I ended up deleting that condition out of the MSI with Orca.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around it.  AutoIT allows you capture events, but it only works consistently if you use keyboard shortcuts.  Stay away from using the mouse at all, as it's not consistent.  It will go through keep track of entered commands and execute them with the same timing as when you capture the commands during a trial-run of the manual install.  Sometimes timing can be an issue, so you have to test.

Not a great way of doing silent installs, but every once in a while you just can't do it with MSI commands.